# Are "Best representation for" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

Latest local example: [How to portray 'lifestyle' in an app logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7915/how-to-portray-lifestyle-in-an-app-logo)

The only similar question I could find in GD Meta is [Is "what's the best / most effective / your favourite logo" on topic?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-whats-the-best-most-effective-your-favourite-logo-on-topic) but it's not exactly the same. It's about visual representation rather than "the best for".

These type of questions have been discussed (and decided to be rejected) in UX meta: https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/629/is-it-time-to-put-an-end-to-icon-for-x-questions

I myself asked a similar question regarding a visual representation for an icon ("Time Range", which is rather a complex thing to show in a single icon) and had it closed. I'm not sure how they are treated in GD generally speaking, but I felt there was a limbo in stacks for them, when some are actually closely related to graphic design and to usability. So I'm wondering what's the right approach for us here.

Edit: I remember seeing some very creative discussions here about how to represent concepts in a new way. If valid questions can be answered here, should the UX people be redirecting theirs to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't feel that these questions are a good fit.  Following *Writers* lead, we have allowed subjective questions involving critiques of designs but they're supposed to involve specific criteria.  It seems that the "best representation" questions always end up being list/poll/idea-gathering questions which are discouraged.

*As a side note, I was going to close "How to portray 'lifestyle'..." as NARQ, but it had close votes on it so I assumed the community would handle it.  However, as of this writing it was still open with 3 close votes so I closed it to avoid having [broken windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).*

---

*Edit:*

Since this answer got accepted, I should probably add a little more context:  Most "best representation" questions are too localized can't effectively be answered by the community.

For example, ["How to portray 'lifestyle'"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/7915/690) will gather different answers from people with different cultures and concepts of lifestyle - and it may likely turn out that none of the answers are useful because the target audience is still a different culture.  It's impossible to answer effectively without knowing all those details, and including such time/application-specific details the question becomes extremely localized.

On the other hand, ["New generation of Save icon..."](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/323/690) is somewhat different.  "Save" refers to a specific act that is ubiquitous in software.  The meaning of "Save" will not change between cultures and refers to a concrete action.

Even though "Save" is a better question than "Lifestyle", it's still not a good fit for this site.  Despite the core action being less culture-specific, introducing new imagery for a well-known action does rely on the culture of the target audience which brings us back to a list of subjective answers.  This is very valuable information to designers and the community at large, but it just doesn't fit with Stack Exchange's purpose of having  "practical, *answerable* questions".

Comment: Thank you for your reply Farray. A question that I really liked is this one: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/323/new-generation-of-save-icon-that-is-not-a-disk/ (and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/save-icon-is-the-floppy-disk-icon-dead) But I guess there can be long way between this and "best icon for blahblah"...

Comment: @yisela there has been a lengthy debate on Meta.stackoverflow about what to do with "historic" questions with many votes and answers but that no longer fit the model for good/acceptable new questions.  It's a tough call.......